# Seeking hardware recommendations for scalable number of I/O

Tags: processor, motherboard

I have a theoretical problem that involves connecting 40 IR sensors and 40 lights to a computer to switch lights on and off based on the input from the IR sensors using python. I found the Arduino boards but it's not a scalable solution. Do y'all have any suggestions?

Comment: a network of Raspberry Pi's all running custom software that does like 20 lights/sensors?

Comment: For the networking part through python, you may be able to get help on StackOverflow

Comment: USB scales pretty well, have you considered USB IR sensors connected into hubs, a single USB controller can support over 200 devices. Or even just dozens of Arduinos (although I'm not sure if the COM ports can go that high) Controlling 40 lights from one arduino is actually very doable using addressable LEDs.

Comment: I need it to be scalable to like 4000 lights and sensors